# Transparent objects seem to be casting black shapes in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

My scene contains transparent objects that fade in but a couple of them seem to be casting black shapes depending on the camera angle.

I've attached a screenshot if anyone can help.

[image]

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the blend or png file... but try replacing one of the texture files with an absolutely clear png (n image content in it). That will show first if the black line in the render is a representation created from the png or from something in the blend. I suspect the png... but this would be a first step.

Comment: If you have enough transparent object behind each other, they can be seen. Try increasing the bouces for transparent objects.

Comment: Are they by any chance coinciding, do they have overlapping edges or geometry? That can confuse the render engine and cause trouble, try shrinking the shapes a little bit so they are not exactly overlapping.